# listing file names based on a pattern in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ls

I am searching for a particular file pattern in hdfs.
My requirement is that , I need to search for a filename with two characters that exists at a particular position.
For Ex:

```
order_items_20181110_transactions.dat
order_items_20181211_transactions.dat
order_items_20181312_transactions.dat
```

I need to select the second file which contains 2018 and 11 just two positions after 2018

I mean is there a way to search which is as follows

```
hdfs dfs ls order_items_2018..11*
```

the two dots specifies any character which is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HDFS command like the below,

`hdfs dfs -ls order_items_2018??11*`

This command will list the file `order_items_20181211_transactions.dat` since this is the only matching result among the given three files. The question mark `?` acts as a wildcard here and considers all the unknown characters at that positions. It helps to get the files of the desired pattern.

Hope this helps.